# Split Strings into Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, split

I have list of lat/lng stored in DB

If checkbox is checked I am getting the value in an array `name='checkbox[]'`.
Consider my HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="123,456" />
<input type="checkbox" value="789,1011" />
```

I'd like the **resulting** data in that form (array of objects)

```js
[
    {lat: "123", lng: "456"},
    {lat: "789", lng: "1011"} 
]
```

I tried this one, but it does not split and store data in `lat` and `lng`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tmp = [];

  $("input[name='checkbox[]']").change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      tmp.push(checked);
      const [lat1[], lon1[]] = tmp.split(',');
    } else {
      tmp.splice($.inArray(checked, tmp), 1);
    }
  });

  $('#show_all_point').on('click', function() {
    alert(lat1, lon1);
  });

});
```

Comment: You mean... `[{lat:0, lng:0}, {lat:0, lng:0}]`

Comment: [{lat:123, lng:456}, {lat:789, lng:1011}]

Comment: PS your input do *not* have a `name` *"checkbox"*, rather a `type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reusable `getPoints()` function which uses jQuery's Elements `.filter()` with the `:checked` selector:

```js
function getPoints() {
  return $(":checkbox").filter(":checked").get().reduce((a, el) => {
    const ll = el.value.split(",");
    a.push({lat:ll[0], lng:ll[1]});
    return a;
  }, []);
}

  

$('#show_all').on('click', function () {
   const points = getPoints();
   alert(JSON.stringify(points, null, 4))
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="123,456" />
<input type="checkbox" value="789,1011" />
<button id="show_all">SHOW SELECTED POINTS</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- [jQuery .get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [jQuery .filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)